# What is the difference between CSVLogger and model.evaluate()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have been using Keras/TF's [`CSVLogger`](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/csv_logger/) in order to save the training and validation accuracies. Then I was plotting those data to check the trajectory of training and validation accuracy or loss.

Yesterday, I read [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/deep_learning_with_keras/deep_learning_with_keras_evaluating_model_performance.htm).

Here, they used `model.evaluate()` to plot the accuracy metric.

What is the difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the big key differences between the two:

model.evaluate() gives a different loss on training data from the one in the training process, while CSVLogger tracks metrics on the validation set after every epoch in the process.

Answer (score 1):

### Log and plot the results

- The `CSVLogger` will save the results **of the training** in a **CSV file**.
- The output of `fit`, normally called `history`, will have the same results ready in a variable, without needing a CSV file.

Their data should be exactly the same.

### Evaluate

The `evaluate` method is **not a log**. It's a method that you call **any time you want**, and will output a **single value** for each loss and metric you have in `compile` for the "current" model.

This is not registered anywhere during training, and this should usually **not be called during training**, unless you create a custom training loop and manually call `evaluate` inside this loop every epoch (this is unnecessary and inconvenient for standard use).

You can use `evaluate` with **any data you want**, including data that was neither in training nor validation data.

### The link you shared

Notice that what they plot is `history`, and `history` is the output of `fit`. It has nothing to do with `evaluate`.

```
plot.plot(history.history['acc'])
plot.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
```

See in the previous page of the link:

```
history = model.fit(...)
```

The link doesn't show exactly "where" they call evaluate, and they're probably doing it "only once after training", just to see the final results of the model (not a log of the training)